# Using setAttributes vs useState in Gutenberg

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I know that setAttributes is used to control attribute values in Gutenberg blocks, and you can store it and save it in editor. I also know that useState is react hook that allows us to save state. What are the main differences between these too, and what are use cases for both, one versus another?

When we use useState and setAttributes, the script is rerendered. When not to use one or another, and when to use it?

Answer (score 2):

Not exact knowledge, more of a feeling:
When building a custom block you'll use an attribute to save e.g. text. The state in e.g. an HOC is used to defined whether or not a modal is visible directly after a user clicked an icon.
So, an attribute is a (more or less) permanent thing, while a state is rather elusive. Did that make any sense to you?